# How to get the type of a Q# operation parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, q#

Suppose we have the following operation in a Q# program:

```
operation MyOperation (num : Int , qubit : Qubit) : Bool {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

If in another C# script in the same namespace we have:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ();
Type[] classes = assembly.GetTypes ();

foreach (var item in classes) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Class : {0}", item.Name);
    List<MethodInfo> methods = new List<MethodInfo> (item.GetMethods ());
    foreach (var method in methods) {         
        // This array contains the parameters of EACH individual method
        ParameterInfo[] p = method.GetParameters();
        foreach (var param in p) {    
            // parameter manipulation
        }  
    }
 }
```

inside `foreach (var param in p) { ... }` we access each single parameter of a specific method. Now if we run the program, the output will be similar to:

```
Class : MyOperation
...
...
```

(where the dots refer to the information of other classes exists in the assembly but are not important in this question.)
As it is seen, each Q# operation is considered as a class (and it makes sense), but my question is how to get the `MyOperation` parameter(s) as in the outcome of the code they are not retrieved?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, each Q# operations generations a C# class that extends the generic class `Operation<I,O>`, so to figure out what the input/output parameters you can take a look at the `BaseType` of the operation, and look at the value of the `GenericTypeArguments[0]` to figure out the input type; the runtime is doing something similar here: https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime/blob/0953d8b632705b9172918ce1588c73ed42088d11/src/Simulation/Core/Generics/GenericCallable.cs#L184

The input type is going to be a `ValueTuple`, to identify the type of individual parameters you will need to check the Type of each of the `Fields`.

Hopefully that makes all sense. Why do you need this information? There are other/betteer ways to do this other than reflection and you might be able to leverage higher level APIs, for example use IQ#, to do this.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the ` IQ#`?